# Swift callback not working

Tags: swift, alamofire

i am trying to get book details using google book api. On error, code calls a callback method but it doesnt get called.

Code courtesy Git Hub example project by - Nicholas Addison

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class BooksManager
{
    static let sharedInstance = BooksManager()

    func getBook(_ isbn: String, callback: @escaping (_ error: NSError?, _ book: Book?)->() )
    {
        Alamofire.request(
            GoogleBookRouter.searchByISBN(isbn: isbn) )
            .responseJSON
            {
                 response in

                if let error = response.result.error
                {
                    logger.debug("Failed to call Google Books API: " + error.localizedDescription)

                    //FIXME:- wrap Alamofire error before returning
                    callback(error as NSError?, nil)
                    return
                }
             }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint and checking the error?

Comment: Is this Swift 3? If yes delete all parameter labels in the completion handler. `(NSError?, Book?)->()`.

Comment: @vadian thank you. Your solution worked. Really appreciate. If you answer then i will accept it.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 all parameter labels in closures have been removed, so simply write

```
func getBook(_ isbn: String, callback: @escaping (NSError?, Book?) -> () ) ...
```